# How to choose certain array based on multiple options?

Tags: arrays, combinations, dropdown

I should preface this by saying I am teaching myself how to learn code, so if anything looks way off, that's why.
I've created some dropdowns and buttons for a list of Cold, Warm, and Multi color options. I have the arrays for the colors all set up; when I click the buttons associated with the color group, I get a randomly chosen color from that color group. However, I want the onclick function of the button to give me two colors when two color groups are mixed. For example: Warm x Cold = blue / yellow; Multi x Red can = Blue / Orange.

I have attempted various strings of code to try and get this to work, but I think I am combining them incorrectly. My most recent attempt is below. most of my attempts have included `$('input[id=colormixer]').click(function ()`  with attempting to associate an id from the dropdown with the correct var(s) with no avail. I get an error that 'getValue' is undefined along with the code simply not working of course.

```html
<html>
<select>
  <option id="set1" name="dropone" value="cold">Cold</option>
  <option id="set2" name="dropone" value="warm">Warm</option>
  <option id="set3" name="dropone" value="multi">Multi</option>
</select>
X
<select>
  <option id="seta" name="droptwo" value="cold">Cold</option>
  <option id="setb" name="droptwo" value="warm">Warm</option>
  <option id="setc" name="droptwo" value="multi">Multi</option>
</select>
<br>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<button onClick="displayValue();" id="colormixer">Color Mixer</button>
<script>

var colddata = ["Blue","Green","Purple"];
var warmdata = ["Orange","Red","Pink",];
var multidata = ["Orange","Red","Pink","Blue","Green","Purple"];
var div = document.getElementById('result');
var current = 0;

function shuffle(o){ 
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
function displayValue()
{
    if $('input[id=colormixer]').click(function () {
    if (this.id == "set1" || "setb"){
    }
  {
  document.getElementById('colormixer').disabled = true;
        return; 
  }
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + colddata[current] + warmdata[current] "<br>";
    current++;
    }
   dropone +- " / " + droptwo;
}

</script>
```

This is what I've tried to get the selection of the dropdown options to change what arrays get spit out onclick of the associated button.

Ideally, I'd love to get this to where if for example, Cold x Warm is entered, onclick I'll get two items from the Multiple color array in the format of "Color / Color". I just don't know where to go from here. Any help in steering me in the right direction would be fantastic! Thank you in advance.